# Galaxy S3 - email notifications not working for emails going to subfolders

Tags: email, notifications

I have set up my GS3 to receive my work emails from Outlook exchange server all works fine, I found the subfolders, (not as easy as you would hope) I am using the defaul email app ( our security protocols are too hard to try to find new apps!)

**Q1:** I can't get the subfolders to stay up to date without going into each folder and synching. Can anyone give clear instrcutions relevant to my phone to resolve this?

**Q2:** I don't get a new email notification when an email goes directly to a folder. I only know about emails going into the normal inbox trays only. This was an issue with my old Blackberry too, but did get resolved eventually by setting up folder access rights. Does anyone have a resolution to this. In the account settings there is no way to change notifications for folders only the whole account so this is turned on and working if limited to the in box only.

thanks

Comment: I don't know about the default email app (didn't use it anymore in the last 2 years), but I don't see how to fix that there: to my experience, automatic checks are limited to the inbox. Which also is the default for most other clients; with [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) you can configure it for any folder.

Answer (score 1):

While you're in each sub-folder go into `Settings->Sync Options` and change to sync automatically or on the schedule that you want.